# Find the function calling the function in JS?

Tags: javascript, debugging, function

What's the best way to find the function that's calling the function?

For example, if I have

```
function first(){
  doSomething();
}

// Lots of code

function doSomething(){
  alert('Somehow, I know that' + ________ + 'function called me...');
  alert('Boink, hit an error, but now you know what function called me');
}
```

Is there any way to get that calling function? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace ______ with `doSomething.caller`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. What if it's undefined, but every instance I call the function in is within another function? Does it mean I'm going crazy?

Comment: Are you using IE? It doesn't support Function.caller.

Comment: I should add that both `caller` and `callee` have been removed in ECMAScript 5, so be careful if you're planning to use this code in the long term.

Comment: I'm using chrome/ffx for debugging / @casa - what's the alternative?